# tomcat8 - external jars directory avail to webapp

Tags: java, classloader, tomcat8

Would like to load/available  jars stored in external directory to web app deployed in tomcat8,

Tried below configuration in MET-INF/context.xml

```
<Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot">
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="E:/external/runtime/"
            internalPath="/"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes/" />
</Resources>
```

but while loading class which is inside external directory jar file getting ClassNotFoundException.

However same configuration is working if .classes files are placed in directory (E:/external/runtime/) but if .jar files placed then not working (.class inside jar files are not loaded).

Expectation: able to load the all jar files in a directory, jar files count may not be determined while configuration, other words, jars will be created and placed in directory at runtime hence need to load the all jars from external directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!..

Comment: This is a bad idea, and violates a lot of accepted best practices.   This is the whole reason for having build tools like Maven or Gradle.  Dependancies should be in your build, not dependent on the app server to have them.   You will get different behaviors on different app servers.

Comment: This is business requirement and cant be done via build tools like maven at the time of deployment, jars will be dynamically generated based on the customer/user preferences. This is conscious decision and support for only tomcat server.

Comment: Ok, so what was just described is actually an even worse idea, and going to be very 
 un-reliable and unstable.

Comment: @BrianC - If you know how to load external jar into tomcat8 then reply your comments otherwise dont waste your/mine time